# Help With Bromwich Inversion Formula Proof

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, laplace-transform, contour-integration, complex-integration

To prove(copied from handwritten notes so possibly wrong):

> **Bromwich Inversion Formula.** Fix $x_0∈ℝ $. If $F$ is complex analytic on $\{z:\Re z > x_0\} $ and for every $x>x_0$, $y↦ F(x + iy )$ is an $L^1$ function, i.e.
>   $$ ∫_{x-i∞ }^{x+i∞} |F(z)| \ \newcommand{\d}{\text{d}}\d z < \infty$$
>   then $f:[0,∞)→\mathbb{C}$ defined by
>   $$f(t) :=\frac{1}{2π i} ∫_{x-i∞ }^{x+i∞} F(z)e^{zt}  \ \d z $$
>   where $x>x_0$ is arbitrary,
>   is a function such that $\mathcal{L}f = F$, where $\mathcal{L}$ is the Laplace transform, $\mathcal{L}f(z) := ∫_0^∞ f(t) e^{-zt} \ \d t$.

I know that $f$ defined above is analytic, since it is the uniform limit of analytic functions (as you lengthen the domain of integration to $x\pm i∞$). My issue is in justifying the penultimate step (coloured $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$) in the following formal calculation:
\begin{align}
 ∫_0^∞ f(t) e^{zt} \ \d t 
&= ∫_0^∞ \left[\frac{1}{2π i} ∫_{x-i∞ }^{x+i∞} F(\xi)e^{\xi t}  \ \d \xi\right] e^{-zt} \ \d t \\
&=  \frac{1}{2π i}∫_{\xi = x-i∞ }^{x+i∞}F(\xi)\underbrace{∫_{t=0}^∞  e^{\xi t}  e^{-zt} \ \d t}_{= \frac{0-1}{\xi-z}}  \ \d \xi \\
&=  -\frac{1}{2π i}∫_{\xi = x-i∞ }^{x+i∞}\frac{F(\xi)}{\xi-z} \d \xi \\
&= \color{blue}{-\frac{1}{2π i}∫_{\gamma}\frac{F(\xi)}{\xi-z} \d \xi} &&(\gamma \text{ a closed curve around $z$}) \\
 &= F(z)
\end{align}
I essentially can't decide on a useful contour of integration (but also it has been a while since I needed complex analysis). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

Edit: I'll take a semicircle around $z$. How would I bound the integral on the semicircular arc? For concreteness I define 
$$L_R = [x-iR, x+iR]\text{ and }C_R = \{x+Re^{iπ t} : t ∈[-1/2 ,1/2] \}$$
$∫_{L_R} \dots \d \xi → ∫_{x-i∞}^{x+i∞} \dots \d \xi$ so I need to show that
$$\int_{C_R} \frac{F(\xi)}{\xi-z} \d \xi \xrightarrow[R→\infty]{} 0 $$

My attempt at finishing this:
\begin{align} \left|\int_{C_R} \frac{F(\xi)}{\xi-z} \d \xi \right| &\leq π R ∫_{-1/2}^{1/2} \left|\frac{F(x + Re^{iπ t})}{x+Re^{iπ t} - z}\right| \d t \leq C ∫_{-1/2}^{1/2} | F(x + Re^{iπ t}) | \ \d t
\end{align}

and I am unsure how to use the '$L^1$ on vertical strips' assumption to conclude this is 0 in the limit.

Comment: Hi @Dr.MV, thanks for the comment. I have attempted to finish the argument (see edit). Can you help me show the integral on the semicircular arc tends to 0?

Comment: Better yet, take the following contour.  The rectangle with vertices $x+iL$, $x-iL$, $L+iL$ and $L-iL$.  Then let $L \to \infty$.   See if that one works better.

Comment: Remember, since for all $x>x_0$, $\int_{x-i\infty}^{x+i\infty} |F(z)|dz < \infty$, then $F(z) \to 0$ as $z=x\pm iL \to x\pm i\infty$.

Comment: Churchill (http://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/46286/209_2005_Article_BF01160095.pdf?sequence=1)                                             adds an assumption that $\lim_{L\to \infty} |F(L+ix)|=0$ uniformly for all $x$

Comment: Yeah, that would do it. I guess I'll email my lecturer and see if she forgot that or some other condition :) May I ask for the name of that book?
edit- thanks for the source :)

Comment: Check the link - you can likely find the title through an internet search.

Comment: thank you for your help :)

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure!  Did you know that you can actually give a comment a vote up?  I found this out recently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume first that $t \gt 0$.  To use Cauchy's theorem, close the integration contour with a circular arc to the left of radius $R$ as follows.

[image]

($D$ is opposite $C$ along the imaginary axis.)  Now consider

$$\oint_{ABCDA} dz \, F(z) e^{z t} $$

where

$$\int_{AB} dz \, F(z) e^{z t}= \int_{x-i \sqrt{R^2-x^2}}^{x+i \sqrt{R^2-x^2}} ds \, F(s) e^{s t} $$

$$\int_{BC} dz \, F(z) e^{z t} = i R \int_{\pi/2-\arcsin{(x/R)}}^{\pi/2} d\theta \, e^{i \theta} \, F \left (R e^{i \theta} \right ) e^{R e^{i \theta} t} $$

$$\int_{CD} dz \, F(z) e^{z t} = i R \int_{\pi/2}^{3 \pi/2} d\theta \, e^{i \theta} \, F \left (R e^{i \theta} \right ) e^{R e^{i \theta} t} $$

$$\int_{DA} dz \, F(z) e^{z t} = i R \int_{3 \pi/2}^{3 \pi/2+\arcsin{(x/R)}} d\theta \, e^{i \theta} \, F \left (R e^{i \theta} \right ) e^{R e^{i \theta} t} $$

First, we can show that the integral over $CD$ vanishes.  This is done by bounding the magnitude of the integral:

$$\begin{align}\left |\int_{CD} dz \, F(z) e^{z t} \right | &\le R \int_{\pi/2}^{3 \pi/2} d\theta \, \left |  F \left (R e^{i \theta} \right ) \right | e^{R t \cos{\theta}}\\ &\le 2 R \operatorname*{max}_{\theta \in [0,\pi]} \left |  F \left (i R e^{i \theta} \right ) \right | \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \, e^{-R t \sin{\theta}} \\ &\le 2 R \operatorname*{max}_{\theta \in [0,\pi]} \left |  F \left (i R e^{i \theta} \right ) \right | \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \, e^{-2 R t \theta/\pi}\\ &\le \frac{\pi}{t} \operatorname*{max}_{\theta \in [0,\pi]} \left |  F \left (i R e^{i \theta} \right ) \right |\end{align}$$

Thus, in order for the integral over $CD$ to vanish, $F$ must satisfy the following condition:

> $$\lim_{R \to \infty} \operatorname*{max}_{\theta \in [0,\pi]} \left |  F \left (i R e^{i \theta} \right ) \right | = 0$$

Now we consider the integral over $BC$.  Note that here we do not have the benefit of a vanishing exponential as we did we $CD$.  We will need another approach to show that this segment too vanishes as $R \to \infty$:

$$\begin{align}\left |\int_{BC} dz \, F(z) e^{z t} \right | &\le R \int_{\pi/2-\arcsin{(x/R)}}^{\pi/2} d\theta \, \left | F \left ( R e^{i \theta} \right ) \right | e^{R t \cos{\theta}} \\ &= R \int_0^{\arcsin{(x/R)}} d\theta \, \left | F \left (i R e^{-i \theta} \right ) \right | e^{R t \sin{\theta}} \\ &\le R \left |F(i R) \right | \int_0^{x/R +O[(x/R)^3]} d\theta \, e^{R t \theta} \left [1+O(\theta^3) \right ] \\ &= \frac{e^{x t}-1}{t}\left | F \left (i R \right ) \right |  + O \left ( \frac1{R^2} \right ) \end{align}$$

To summarize, the integral over $BC$ vanishes as $R \to \infty$ under the same conditions as that for the integral over $CD$.  The integral over $DA$ vanishes for the same reasons.

Thus, under the highlighted condition above, one may invoke Cauchy's theorem as you have done above and prove the inversion formula.

When $t \lt 0$, close to the right.  In that case, there is only a single circular arc and the integral vanishes for the same reasons as discussed for the integral over $CD$.

Comment: Hi Ron, thanks for the answer. I'm giving it a read now :)

Comment: I think I understand. Am I right in saying that assuming the stated condition for $F$, what you have shown is that I need not take an integral over a vertical strip for $f$, which then carries through to the calculation for $\mathcal{L}f$? Thanks very much :)

Comment: @CalvinKhor: I'm not entirely sure what you mean.  What I have provided are the conditions by which you may apply Cauchy's theorem in your blue equation.  I show here that the integral over the arc vanishes when $F$ satisfies the limit condition highlighted.

Comment: Sorry, I think I understand but can't articulate myself. In your answer the integrand for $f$ appears, whereas the integral in blue is an integral of $F(z)/(z-w)$. Regardless I do believe this is correct.