# Inverse Laplace Transform Formula

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to learn how to evaluate inverse Laplace transforms without the aid of a table of transforms, and I've found the inversion formula:
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{F\}(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma-i\infty}^{\gamma+i\infty}F(s)e^{st}ds$$ I'm currently in high school, and I don't a lot of knowledge in terms of complex analysis, but I do have a pretty good base in calculus, so if anyone could help me out, it'd be great if you could also explain some of the complex analysis methods that may be involved in evaluating this integral.
A step by step solution for the ILT of $F(s)=\frac{1}{s}$ would be awesome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect you would find the Fourier transform easier to understand, since it only requires real integrals (albeit with complex parameters). Your question as it stands is going to require explaining analytic functions, complex line integrals, Cauchy's theorem, and the Residue Theorem, which is probably at least 5 sides of A4 if done with no motivation or examples.

Comment: And once you have the Fourier transform, it's relatively easy to derive the appropriate formulae for the Laplace transform, although some care must be taken with limits.

Comment: hm, I'll give a go at Fourier transforms and learn along the way then.

Comment: @JerryW. Since the problem seems to be solved, you might want to [mark one of the answers as accepted](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the check mark (✓) icon next to the answer on the left. Doing so will mark the question as answered, and will also award both you and the author of the answer a few reputation points.

Comment: ah yes, sorry I’m pretty new to this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before I start, it would be very hard to do this kind of transform without learning how to evaluate contour integrals, how to evaluate residues (it gets more complicated for something like $\frac{1}{z^3})$ (*mentioned in the comments*), and Jordan's Lemma to justify the integral along the circular part to go to $0$.

However this question might be useful to someone who knows a little more about complex analysis, so I'll run through the evaluation of the inverse Laplace transform of $F(s)=\dfrac{1}{s}$ as an example.

---

As you have seen, the integral in question is $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma-i\infty}^{\gamma+i\infty}F(s)e^{st}ds$. What do the limits mean?

Firstly to determine $\gamma$, you need to examine the function $F(s)e^{st}$, and more specifically, where its singularities lie. In this example, there is one singularity, at $s=0$. You choose $\gamma$ to be a real number which lies to the *right* of all the singularities of your function when sketched in the complex plane. Here, since our singularity is at $0$, we can choose $\gamma$ to be, say $1$. Then the $\pm i\infty$ simply mean to express the contour going up to $\infty$ and down to $-\infty$ (though this is technically also $\infty$) from the point $\gamma$ on the complex plane. So far we have described a contour which is just a vertical line, which has equation $Re(z)=\gamma$.

Now the question is, how do we evaluate this integral? This is where the complex analysis methods come in. We first draw a contour as follows:

[image]

The ends $A$ and $B$ are at the points $\gamma-iR$ and $\gamma+iR$ respectively. Taking the limit as $R\rightarrow\infty$, the line $AB$ becomes the integral we want. Meanwhile the part of the circle which goes from $B$ to $C$ all the way round to $A$ becomes a very big circle when we take this limit. There is a theorem, called Jordan's Lemma, which can be used to show that the integral along this contour goes to $0$ in specific cases, based on what $F(s)$ is. In this example, it does work. So as we take the limit, the integral along this contour is exactly the same as the integral we wish to calculate.

Next - how do we evaluate the integral along this contour? This requires the residue theorem. In short, you evaluate something called a residue at each singularity inside the contour. Here, that residue is at $s=0$. The sum of all the residues inside a contour is equal to the integral along the contour, divided by $2\pi i$, just as we want. So to work out this integral you need to work out the residues at each singularity, and add them up.

In your example, $F(s)=\frac{1}{s}$, so $$Res_{s=0}(F(s))=\lim_{s\rightarrow0} \underbrace{\frac{e^{st}}{s}}_{\text{the integral}}\times (s-\underbrace{z_0}_{\text{where the singularity is}})=\lim_{s\rightarrow0}(e^{st})=1.$$

So we conclude that this is the inverse Laplace transform of $F(s)=\frac{1}{s}$. $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma-i\infty}^{\gamma+i\infty}F(s)e^{st}ds=1$$

Comment: Thank you so much, this made a lot of sense. Just to be sure, since the singularity is at s=0, that means z nought is 0, right? Also, what would I need to do if there were more than one singularity?

Comment: Yes, that is what $z_0$ means. If there were multiple singularities, e.g. $\frac{1}{z(z^2-1)}$ then you work out the residues at all of these singularities ($z=0,\pm1$) and add them together to get the value of $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int$.

Comment: If there was a more complex singularity, say $1/z^2$, then this is called a pole of order $2$, and so a different formula is required to work out the residue. In general, the residue at a pole of order $n$ at the point $z_0$ is $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}\left(\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}((z-z_0)^n f(z))\right)$.

Comment: What would I do if the singularity isn’t a real number? For example $\frac{1}{s^{2}+1}$?

Comment: Exactly the same thing, with $z_0$ being $\pm i$. For example if you want to find the residue of $f(s)=\frac{1}{s^2+1}e^{st}$ at $s=i$, then you use the formula in my previous comment as follows: $$\lim_{s\rightarrow i}(s-i) f(s)=\lim_{s\rightarrow i}\frac{e^{st}}{s+i}=\frac{e^{it}}{2i}$$ And you can do similarly for $s=-i$.

Comment: Right, I just tried that and it worked. But what would I write for $\gamma$ in the bounds of integration? Since $\gamma$ has to be real.

Comment: You could just write $\gamma=1$ or $2$, as long as it lies to the right of all the singularities. That is, as long as $\gamma>\max_{z_0\in\Omega}{Re(z_0)}$, where $\Omega$ is the set of all singularities. In your example, $\Omega=\{-i,i\}$, so $\max_{z_0\in\Omega}{Re(z_0)}=\max\{0,0\}=0$, so you would just need to choose a $\gamma>0$. When actually evaluating the integral, you'll notice it doesn't really matter what $\gamma$ is for these cases, but for more complicated cases (which would need complex analysis to explain), $\gamma$ becomes important.

Comment: Nice picture... https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1262088/help-with-bromwich-inversion-formula-proof/1264372#1264372

Comment: @RonGordon Haha, sorry, I just used one which seemed appropriate off Google Images, I didn't know it was yours.

Comment: Hey, quick follow up question, is it possible to actually evaluate this as an integral instead of using residues?

Comment: When integrating in the complex plane, you usually use contour integration, as I have done in this example. However you could do a substitution, as ALB did in the other answer, in which case you'd get a real integral which can then be evaluated. The residue method is quite a lot easier though in my opinion, evaluating $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{\gamma+it}}{\gamma+it}dt$ looks quite tricky at first glance.

Answer (score 1):

A complex integral can be defined via the path taken by the contour parameterized by a real variable, that is for $t\mapsto z(t)$, $ a \leq t \leq b$
$$
\int_C f(z)dz = \int_a^b f(z(t))z'(t)dt.
$$
In the inverse Laplace transform the parameterization is $t \mapsto \gamma+it$ and $-\infty \leq t \leq \infty$. We thus have
$$
L^{-1}(F(s)) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(\gamma+it)e^{\gamma+it}dt.
$$
Generally we take $\gamma = 0$ but since your example has a pole at the origin you will need to take a different approach. As chappers mentioned this would involve a lengthy discussion of the concepts in analytic function theory.

Comment: Really, $\gamma$ is chosen so that any singularities of $F$ lie to the left of the contour, and if $f$ is absolutely integrable, $\gamma=0$ will do. But even explaining that requires a fair amount of complex analysis...

Comment: @Chappers ok, I see how that works. Seeing the LT in terms of classical control makes you think $\gamma = 0$ is the default, but according to your remark that is actually due to assumptions regarding the open-loop stability of a system.

Comment: I'll take your word for it; not my area of expertise!

Comment: Interesting, I don't fully understand your explanation right now but I'll be sure to come back to it when I know more complex analysis, thanks for the answer.