# Fixed point of laplace transform

Tags: laplace-transform

The laplace transform $L$ of $f(x)$ is defined as

$$L[f] = \int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-st}dt.$$

Does there exist a distribution, besides constant functions, $g(x)$ such that $L[g(x)] = g(s)?$

Comment: I did read that but I don't quite follow. It looks like it's saying the fixed point is a set of numbers, and that's it, it doesn't seem quite accurate considering a fixed point of just the Fourier transform might be $e^{x^2/2}.$ This is a little bit more general because $s$ in general can be complex, not just $i.$

Comment: Answer to that question provides an explicit construction of the “fixed” function.

Comment: Note that the constant function does NOT satisfy your criteria, since L[c]=c/s

Comment: Take the inverse laplace transform of both sides and use [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2242548/inverse-laplace-transform-formula) on page $3$ of the pdf to get the equivalent equation $f(x)=L^{-1}(f(s))=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(a+it) e^{a+it}dt$